# Cakephp url links

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to make all my pages/urls seo friendly including the dynamic ones but i'm stuck at it.

I made it work for the static pages for example :

```
$routes->connect('/:lang/about',['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'about'] );
```

But when i add the following to routes

```
$routes->connect('/:lang/:slug',['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'index'], ['pass' => ['slug']] );
```

All the pages redirect to MyController even the static ones, so i'm wondering if there is any solution to that one.

Thanks.

Comment: you need something like: `$routes->connect('/:lang/posts/:slug'..`

Comment: @madalinivascu i don't wan't to add anything static..

Comment: what do you mean by static?

Comment: the name of the controller (Posts) i don't wan't that

Comment: why don't you want that?what is stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"catch-all" routes (like the one in your question) need to go **after** other routes. This way the static routes are checked first and "catch-all" are used only when no other routes were matched

**For example**:

```
$routes->connect('/:lang/about',['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'about'] );
$routes->connect('/:lang/:slug',['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'index'], ['pass' => ['slug']] );
```

**Instead of** (notice the ordering):

```
$routes->connect('/:lang/:slug',['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'index'], ['pass' => ['slug']] );
$routes->connect('/:lang/about',['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'about'] );
```